# pymodbus how to test my serial RTU server over a real serial port

Tags: python, pytest, pymodbus, pytest-mock

I try to write a pytest for my pymodbus RTU server where I want to write a 32bit float encoded value to the server and compare it with the servers own register read method.  The server looks like this:

```py
class ModbusRTUServer:
    P_target_address = 0x33
    def __init__(self, port, timeout, baudrate):
        self.thread = None
        self.port = port
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.baudrate = baudrate
        self.block = ModbusSequentialDataBlock.create()
        self.store = ModbusSlaveContext(hr=self.block, ir=self.block)
        self.context = ModbusServerContext(slaves=self.store)
        self.P_target = 0

    def _run_server_threaded(self):
        StartSerialServer(
            self.context,
            framer=ModbusRtuFramer,
            port=self.port,
            timeout=self.timeout,
            baudrate=self.baudrate,
        )
        l.debug("StartSerialServer() ended.")

    def run_server(self):
        self.thread = Thread(target = self._run_server_threaded)
        self.thread.start()

    def stop_server(self):
        StopServer()

    def get_P_target_float32(self):
        return BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(
            self.block.getValues(ModbusRTUServer.P_target_address, 2), 
            byteorder=Endian.Big, wordorder=Endian.Big
        ).decode_32bit_float()
```

And here is the test, that does not work:

```py
@patch("twisted.internet.serialport.SerialPort")
def test_modbus_rtu_server_get_P_target_float32_should_be_big_endian_encoded(mock_sp) -> None:
    with patch('twisted.internet.reactor') as mock_reactor:
        m, s = os.openpty()

        server = ModbusRTUServer(os.ttyname(s), test_server_timeout, test_server_baudrate)
        server.run_server()
        assert mock_reactor.run.call_count == 1

        val_f = -3.33
        builder = BinaryPayloadBuilder(byteorder=Endian.Big, wordorder=Endian.Big)
        builder.add_32bit_float(val_f)
        print(builder.to_registers()) # [49237, 7864]

        client = ModbusSerialClient(method='rtu', baudrate=test_server_baudrate, timeout = test_server_timeout, port=os.ttyname(m))
        client.connect()
        assert client.is_socket_open() == True

        client.write_registers(ModbusRTUServer.P_target_address, builder.to_registers())
        assert server.get_P_target_float32() >= val_f - 0.01
        assert server.get_P_target_float32() <= val_f + 0.01
```

These are the log messages I end up with:

```
>           assert server.get_P_target_float32() <= val_f + 0.01
E           assert 4.775518667735688e-39 <= (-3.33 + 0.01)
E            +  where 4.775518667735688e-39 = <bound method ModbusRTUServer.get_P_target_float32 of <smc.ModbusRTUServer object at 0x7f2353f78d60>>()
E            +    where <bound method ModbusRTUServer.get_P_target_float32 of <smc.ModbusRTUServer object at 0x7f2353f78d60>> = <smc.ModbusRTUServer object at 0x7f2353f78d60>.get_P_target_float32

tests/test_modbus.py:47: AssertionError
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured log call --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO     pymodbus.server.asynchronous:asynchronous.py:327 Starting Modbus Serial Server on /dev/pts/12
DEBUG    pymodbus.server.asynchronous:asynchronous.py:223 Running in spawned thread
DEBUG    pymodbus.payload:payload.py:125 [49237, 7864]
DEBUG    pymodbus.payload:payload.py:125 [49237, 7864]
DEBUG    pymodbus.transaction:transaction.py:139 Current transaction state - IDLE
DEBUG    pymodbus.transaction:transaction.py:144 Running transaction 1
DEBUG    pymodbus.transaction:transaction.py:273 SEND: 0x0 0x10 0x0 0x33 0x0 0x2 0x4 0xc0 0x55 0x1e 0xb8 0x91 0x90
DEBUG    pymodbus.client.sync:sync.py:76 New Transaction state 'SENDING'
DEBUG    pymodbus.transaction:transaction.py:287 Changing transaction state from 'SENDING' to 'WAITING FOR REPLY'
DEBUG    pymodbus.transaction:transaction.py:303 Transaction failed. (Modbus Error: [Invalid Message] No response received, expected at least 2 bytes (0 received)) 
DEBUG    pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:rtu_framer.py:240 Frame - [b''] not ready
DEBUG    pymodbus.transaction:transaction.py:465 Getting transaction 0
DEBUG    pymodbus.transaction:transaction.py:224 Changing transaction state from 'PROCESSING REPLY' to 'TRANSACTION_COMPLETE'
DEBUG    pymodbus.payload:payload.py:312 [52, 52]
DEBUG    pymodbus.payload:payload.py:368 [b'\x004', b'\x004']
DEBUG    pymodbus.payload:payload.py:312 [52, 52]
DEBUG    pymodbus.payload:payload.py:368 [b'\x004', b'\x004']
```

When I run this server on a real serial port connected to another raspi and start the very same client example there, everything works fine.

I searched in all examples and tests but found no solution for this problem or an example how to make such a test over a real serial port. Any help is very appreciated!